# mysql join tables with an if condition?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

Im trying to join 5 tables that look somewhat like this

**post table**

ID | product | user-us | make-id | dealer-id |  pending | .... 30 other columns ... |

**make table**

ID | make |

**state table**

prefix | state | city | zip

**members table**

ID | name | email | password | zip | dealer-id

**dealer table**

ID | dealer name | city | state | zip | address | phone

MySql query looks like this

```
    SELECT *
    FROM `post` AS p
        JOIN (`make` AS m, `state` AS s, `members` AS mb, `dealer` AS d)
        ON (p.Make = m.id AND p.state = s.id AND p.id = mb.id AND mb.dealer-id = d.id)
   WHERE p.pending != '1'
```

The problem is this query only returns rows that **member.dealer-id = dealer.id**,  And if i use a LEFT JOIN, it returns all the correct rows, BUT all columns in tables make, state, members and dealer will be NULL. which it shouldn't be because i need the info in those tables.

Is there away i can only join the `dealer` table if **member.dealer-id is > 0**? i could add a row in the dealer table with id 0, but there has to be a better way.

Comment: Just to understand your question better: What is the advantage for in returning no values instead of NULL?

Comment: information in tables `post`, `make`,`state` and `members` are important. only if member is a dealer, include the dealer table info

Comment: so the only work around is to add a row with id = 0 in the dealer table?

Comment: Important is the way, you deal with the data afterwards. If there is no dealer information just ignore it or remove it with/in the programming code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you code your joins in the normal way, use `LEFT JOIN` only on the `dealer` table:

```
SELECT *
FROM post AS p
JOIN make AS m ON p.Make = m.id
JOIN state AS s ON  p.state = s.id
JOIN`members AS mb ON p.id = mb.id
LEFT JOIN dealer AS d ON mb.dealer_id = d.id
WHERE p.pending != '1'
```

This will automatically only join to dealer if the `member.dealer-id` is greater than zero.

btw, I have never seen a query join coded like yours before. If I had, I would have assumed it would not execute due to a syntax error - it looks that strange.

Comment: thanks! yeah your joins look so much less confusing. will keep it in mind. performance wise, any optimization tips? coz my post table can get pretty big. right now its already 150k rows. or does this work perfect?

Comment: This will perform very well (sorry if you read my previous comment which said it wouldn't perform well - I thought I was commenting on a different answer)